# How do I determine the expected number of trials to collect each item, each collection set, and every item in the collection?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, probability, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm attempting to do this for a game project in google sheets ([my sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yfYpKqhEAOUxpBm7QH0melAiAGfp5GhKXXqunfiA6HE/edit?usp=sharing)). Basically the player opens up boxes that contain 5 items (5 trials) each with their own weight of appearing in the box. Each collection set contains 12 items with 6 commons, 3 rares, 2 epics, and 1 legendary. There are 5 collection sets total.

How do I figure out (preferably in the spreadsheet) the expected number of boxes to open to get: each item, each collection set, and all 5 collections sets.

Answer (score 0):

one cell formula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(B2:B/SUM(B2:B)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This is just telling me the probability right? I'm looking for expected number of boxes opened until I collect each item, each set of items, and finally all of the items in the list.

Comment: can you include example of what you want in your sheet?

Comment: I added some examples in the sheet. I'm not sure if I need to simulate each box opening or if there's a formula for determining how many boxes opened until it's likely it will appear in the box.

I suppose this is similar to a dice roll simulator except each "side" has a different probability.